# Javascript Vanilla - How to attach event listener on element inside ajax content?

Tags: javascript, ajax, selector

If in Jquery we can simply delegate the event in `<body>` like this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[data-method]', function () {
  // event action here
});
```

But how we do that in Vanilla Javascript?

**Note: `<a data-method="">` is created inside ajax content**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an event listener to `body`, and then check to see if the `event.target.matches` the desired selector:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (!event.target.matches('a[data-method]')) return;
  console.log('click');
});

setTimeout(() => {
  const a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
  a.setAttribute('data-method', 'foo');
  a.textContent = 'aaa';
}, 100);
```

Comment: An additional info. Using `event.target.closest()` is more better than `event.target.matches()`